# How to lock the website to fit inside the viewport without being able to scroll horizontally on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been getting reports from a couple of users "Android users in most cases" that the website is opening as a white screen on their phones.

After some troubleshooting, I found out that if you zoom out and scroll around, you will find the actual website.

When you open the website, the viewport is showing a large white screen and the actual website is inside it.

I added this to the header.php `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1">` and its not getting fixed.

Any idea why and how to lock the website content to the viewport cadre?

Screenshot sent by users: [when they first open the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTa3i.jpg)

Screenshot sent by users: [After they scroll right and zoom out a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKkN3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: viewport seems have some issue on live site <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Any idea what I should replace this with?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

First try changing your viewport tag to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You could try adding the following CSS:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You could also try disabling zoom by adapting your viewport tag with the following:

```
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no
```

You might also want to look at the CSS touch-action property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: Before I added the current meta tag, the previous one was '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' and the issue was still showing.

Comment: should I add just maximum-scale=1.0, userscalable=no to do the trick?

Comment: You could try, do you have a link to the live site?

Comment: I see you adjusted the viewport tag? Seems to work fine on Google Pixel now.

Comment: The thing is that this is happening to a handful of people. I have note 5 and its working fine. I hate when there's a user per user issue...

Comment: Would probably be worth testing on browserstack with a device where the issue is present.